# What is the philosophy behind using Objective-C in iOS? Why not C++?

Tags: c++, objective-c, c, ios

Having involved in C++ projects for more than ten years, it is really a big question for me that why Objective-C has been used as the base programming language on iOS. Taking a look at Objective-C spec, it seems that it is more dynamic than C++ in binding variables to their types, as a result it is not more efficient than C++. Can someone tell me what the philosophy behind using this language is?

Comment: Maybe because iOS comes from Apple, and they use Objective-C for everything already?

Comment: Also note that Android uses Java (more or less), which is also not more efficient than C++. And others go with HTML5/Javascript.

Comment: @thilo: Yes, you are right. Taking a look at Objective-C history, it seems that this PL has been one of the favorite PLs of Steve jobs, when he was working at neXt Co.. But isn’t there any technical philosophy behind this adoption?

Comment: Because it provided Apple with a ready-made framework: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NeXT

Comment: It's probably worth pointing out that the choice of Objective-C was made more than 25 years ago before C++ was even standardized.

Comment: @nos: you are right. Performance is not everything. But the big Q is that why preferring Objective-C to C++?

Comment: This kind of question is probably going to get better replies at [Programmers](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: @FirozeLafeer: well, that's hardly an argument, after all. "was made more than 25 years ago" - but hello, we are 25 years later and C++ IS already standardized. It doesn't make much sense to keep using a language like Objective-C.

Comment: @Griwes well no, the issue is that Apple/NeXT have been using this language for a very long time. Not a decision taken in 2007 or something. As Thilo and Jorgen correctly point out, using the same language means being able to reuse many other things developed over those 25 years. (and of course Apple also uses C++ and even Objective-C++ and you can use those in your apps as well.)

Comment: Objective c is a lot more efficient than c++ in the engineering time needed to create a solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no philosophy per sé, Apple bought Next Computer and their Operating System NeXTSTEP, which provided an objective-c API.

Mac OS X is based on on the NeXTSTEP system, and in turn, iOS is based on OS X, so it's a natural progression. This also explains why a whole bunch of classes start with NS.

Comment: Thanks. It seems true, but isn't there any technical issues behind this long use of this language?

Answer (score 1):

Read [this](http://www.mactech.com/articles/mactech/Vol.13/13.03/CandObjectiveCCompared/index.html) or ask Tom Love & Brad Cox :p

Comment: Well, after reading a part, it looks like author isn't/wasn't able to learn C++ properly, blame the language and want to use easier language. Well, it's his choice, but IMHO it's plainly stupid to say "I don't know how to use it, it sucks!".

Comment: @Griwes: Well, that's not what he's saying; he's saying "It seems impossible to properly learn C++; and that doesn't strike me as a Good Thing™.", at least insofar as I can see. But then again, I read the whole thing, so I might be biased.

Comment: "It seems" is clearly a way to express "I can't do it". But it doesn't mean everyone can't do it.

Comment: @Griwes: Well, C++ inarguably has bizarre and esoteric features as the article points out. And that certainly isn't a Good Thing™; and it does make it harder to learn. Impossible? Probably not. Less than worthwhile? Probably.

Comment: Well, the features make the language powerful, don't them?

Comment: @Griwes: Sure, powerful. But that just means you are shooting yourself in the foot with a bazooka rather than a gun…

Comment: No, features do not make a language powerful. The right features might. And you do *not* need a lot of features. Lisp is powerful, as is Smalltalk. Ruby has more features, but is not more powerful.

Answer (score 0):

Basically, they are both parallel developments to make C object oriented. NeXT picked Objective c, and as a result Apple uses it now.

Read this: http://luminaryapps.com/blog/objective-c-a-history/

Answer (score 0):

iOS is Mac OS X, [ON MOBILE](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/RecycledINSPACE)! On Mac OS X; the lingua franca is Objective-C.

This, in turn, is because Mac OS X is NeXTStep, [ON A MAC](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/RecycledINSPACE)!; and the language used for the NeXTStep frameworks is Objective-C.

As has been pointed out, Objective-C predates C++; and SmallTalk, upon which Objective-C is based, while a neat language, isn't really suited for large-scale development. In many ways it was the best of limited options, but it has nonetheless stood the test of time, and holds up well, even today.

Comment: You are downvoting an answer because of personal grief towards the answerer, and not because of its content! Really funny!